# How can i use SPI on Arduino Due to communicate with AD7124-8 correctly

Tags: arduino, spi, adc, arduino-c++

I want to read data from AD7124-8 with arduino Due via SPI. I found several libraries, but i dont get anything back from my ADC modul. By using an Oscilloscope i made sure my Arduino sends data via MOSI, SCK and CS work aswell. Just the MISO dataline doesnt get me anything back.

I first used this library (https://github.com/NHBSystems/NHB_AD7124), but decided to use a much easier Code to just make sure everything is working fine. I tried to to talk to the communication register to get the ID of my device from the ID register. You can find the registers on page 39 of the datasheet :https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad7124-8.html .

Im sending 0x00 and 0x05 to get back the 0x14 which should be the correct ID. Just zeros arriving (shown by Osci).
I found a solution in a Forum, but im not sure about why it differs with the data sheet:
https://ez.analog.com/data_converters/precision_adcs/f/q-a/24046/ad7124-8-for-arduino-due
when i use it the code stops running at the Line: value[0] = SPI.transfer(0x00);
They send 0x40 at the beginning, too.

Here my simple Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>

// Physical Pins
const int csPin = 10;
int value[7] {0};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin(10);
  
  SPI.setClockDivider(10, 128);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE3);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(csPin, LOW);
  //SPI.transfer(csPin, 0x00);
  SPI.transfer(csPin,0x00,SPI_CONTINUE); //Tell Communication Register you are going to read ID register
  SPI.transfer(csPin,0x05);
  //SPI.transfer(csPin,0x00);            //Get data from Communication Register
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);
  delay(1);
  Serial.print(value[0],HEX);
}
```

I hope someone can help me out.
Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this may not related to your question, but you are using old SPI methods `setClockDivider()`, `setDataMode()`, and `setBitOrder()` that has been deprecated since 2014. It is recommend to use use transactional SPI APIs which I have some explanation [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79728/when-is-spi-begintransaction-required/79760#79760).

Secondly, according to datasheet page 85, to access the ID register, you send one-byte to specific which register that you need to communicate with. Your code send two bytes, `0x00` and `0x05`, which is incorrect.

Furthermore, based on page 78 of the datasheet, in order to read a register, bit 6 need to be set to 1 for a read operation, and 0 for a write operation.

Try the following code:

```c
#include <SPI.h>

#define READ_REGISTER 0B01000000  // bit 6 set to 1 for read operation
#define ID_REGISTER   0x05

const int csPin = 10;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);  // set csPin to HIGH to prevent false trigger
  pinMode(csPin,OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin();
}

void loop() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(84000000/128, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite(csPin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(READ_REGISTER | ID_REGISTER);  // read register 5
  uint8_t id = SPI.transfer(0x00);            // get the id
  digitalWrite(csPin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  Serial.print(id,HEX);
}
```

Comment: BTW, the SPI is set based on the assumption that Due is operated at 84MHz, and I use the clock divide of 128 from your sketch.

Comment: Hey hcheung, thank you for your Code, i used it and it worked, but just after i made sure to connect AVDD with 3.3V_AVDD and AVSS with GND physically. I think thats why i never even got an answer from the MISO dataline. So Guys make sure to keep that in mind, when u use the ADC 6 Click module (https://www.mikroe.com/adc-6-click)!! There was no description to that.

Comment: Any experienced electronics engineer know about AVDD and AVSS, and how to connected it. It is kind of "assumed" knowledge when working with noise and electronics ESD. It is less known by the people coming from pure computer/programming background. You can read [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/279844/236376) for the explanation.